# Invoking Main Controller function from Modal Controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Problem Summary** 
I want to invoke getCost function present in main controller, from modal controller.
Pseudo-Code for this to explain the problem follows.

I am am opening modal dialog as follows:

```
....
//I want to invoke this getCost function from the Modal Controller
//So i pass it via 'resolve'
      $scope.getCost = function() {
            return i*x+y;//calculates and returns some cost
       }

        $modal.open({
             templateUrl: '/html/MyModal.html',
             controller: MyModalCtrl,
             resolve: {
            getCostNow: function () {
                return $scope.getCost;
             }
         }
        });
.....
```

And in MyModalCtrl this is like:

```
var MyModalCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, $http, getCostNow) {


 function updateOrder()
  {
     //Trying to invoke getCost function reference here
     //But this does not work.
     var theCurrentCostIs = getCostNow();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (notice the scope:$scope):

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/html/MyModal.html',
    controller: MyModalCtrl,     
    scope:$scope,
    resolve: {
        getCostNow: function () {
           return $scope.getCost;
        }
    }
});
```

You can then use event listeners, to send an event:

```
$scope.$emit(name, args);
```

And in the parent listen for the event:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data) { console.log(data); });
```